# displaying clickable text WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to present some text in the GUI and give the user that ability to double click it.
I want to catch this event and deal with it.

I thought to do it like this :

```
 <TextBlock   
        Height="39" 
        TextElement.FontSize="18" 
        FontFamily="Verdana"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Name="Filelink"
        Padding="5,0,0,0"
        TextDecorations="Underline"
        Text="{Binding Path=FilePath}"/>
```

But seems that it's not easy to deal with clicks in `TextBlock` .

Any ideas what is the best way to present a click able text.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022109/wpf-dynamically-created-text-with-clickable-links-in-it-via-binding ?

Comment: Wouldn't this be confusing? How would the user know he can double click on it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can embed a hyberlink in a Textblock as shown in this example

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Reviews.xaml">Click Me </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

You can also handle the hyperlinks Click event to call Navigate for example

Comment: This answer does not help in handling the Doubleclick event but I upvoted because I think using a hyperlink is a really good practice to show that a text is clickable.

Answer (score 25):

If you want clickable text you can just restyle a `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Text here" Click="Click_Handler">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <ContentPresenter />
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830164/what-is-the-best-way-to-simulate-a-click-with-mouseup-mousedown-events-or-othe).

Comment: As I see it this is the right solution, because then  you can also bind commands to the button. when manipulating a textbox you won't have a CommandBindable control

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a `Label` and listen for the [`MouseDoubleClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.mousedoubleclick.aspx) event (although I do agree with Xin's comment about usability)?

Answer (score 1):

If using a `Label` or a `Hyperlink` won't work in your situation, you could take the approach of a creating a new derived `TextBlock` that simply defines a new `DoubleClick` routed event which bubbles up through the tree:

```
public class ClickableTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    #region Overrides

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        if (e.ClickCount == 2)
        {
            RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(DoubleClickEvent, this));
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region DoubleClick RoutedEvent

    public static readonly RoutedEvent DoubleClickEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("DoubleClick",
        RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(ClickableTextBlock));

    public event RoutedEventHandler DoubleClick
    {
        add { AddHandler(DoubleClickEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(DoubleClickEvent, value); }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

This control can be used in the same way as your standard `TextBlock`. In this example, double clicking on the `TextBlock` will raise the `DoubleClick` event which is then acted upon by the parent `StackPanel` to start an animation:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Background="LightGreen">
        <StackPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="l:ClickableTextBlock.DoubleClick">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         Duration="0:0:1"
                                         To="0.5"
                                         FillBehavior="Stop"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </StackPanel.Triggers>
        <l:ClickableTextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Background="LightPink"
                              Text="Double Click to change parent's opacity" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Hope this helps!