# Binding text to attached property

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, textblock, attached-properties

My question is similar to this: [WPF Generate TextBlock Inlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582893/wpf-generate-textblock-inlines) but I don't have enough reputation to comment.  Here is the attached property class:

```
public class Attached
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FormattedText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TextBlock),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;
        if (textBlock == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var formattedText = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        formattedText = string.Format("<Span xml:space=\"preserve\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">{0}</Span>", formattedText);

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(formattedText)))
        {
            var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this attached property class and trying to apply it to a textblock to make the text recognize inline values like bold, underline, etc from a string in my view model class.  I have the following XAML in my textblock:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" my:Attached.FormattedText="test" />
```

However I get nothing at all in the textblock when I start the program.  I also would like to bind the text to a property on my view model eventually but wanted to get something to show up first...

Sorry this is probably a newbie question but I can't figure out why it's not working.  It doesn't give me any error here, just doesn't show up.  If I try to bind, it gives me the error:

> {"A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'SetFormattedText' property of type 'TextBlock'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject."}

Comment: At StackOverflow, you are *supposed* to ask questions as questions and *not* as comments and it's good that you provided a link to the other question. However, you need to provide *[all of the relevant code that is required to reproduce your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*, as this is one reason that the community might decide to delete your question.

Comment: Ok sorry, thanks for the pointers.  I updated to include the source code for the class I'm trying to use and a little more detail of where I'm trying to go with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the type of property needs to be a class name, not the type `TextBlock`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "FormattedText",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(TextBlock), <----- Here
```

Second, the handler is not called, it must be registered here:

```
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, 
                              FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                              YOUR_PropertyChanged_HANDLER)
```

Thirdly, an example to work, you need to specify the input string like this:

```
<Bold>My little text</Bold>
```

Working example is below:

`XAML`

```
<Window x:Class="InlineTextBlockHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:InlineTextBlockHelp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="TestText"
                   this:AttachedPropertyTest.FormattedText="TestString"
                   Width="200"
                   Height="100" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />

        <Button Name="TestButton"
                Width="100"
                Height="30"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Content="TestClick" 
                Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string inlineExpression = "<Bold>Once I saw a little bird, go hop, hop, hop.</Bold>";
        AttachedPropertyTest.SetFormattedText(TestText, inlineExpression);
    }
}

public class AttachedPropertyTest
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FormattedText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(AttachedPropertyTest),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, FormattedTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;

        if (textBlock == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var formattedText = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        formattedText = string.Format("<Span xml:space=\"preserve\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">{0}</Span>", formattedText);

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(formattedText)))
        {
            var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Initially be plain text, after clicking on the `Button` will be assigned to inline text.

**`Example for MVVM version`**

To use this example in MVVM style, you need to create the appropriate property in the `Model/ViewModel` and associate it with the attached dependency property like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="TestText"
           PropertiesExtension:TextBlockExt.FormattedText="{Binding Path=InlineText, 
                                                                    Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           Width="200"
           Height="100" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

Property in `Model/ViewModel` must support method `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Here is a full sample:

**`AttachedProperty`**

```
public class TextBlockExt
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FormattedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FormattedText",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(TextBlockExt),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure, FormattedTextPropertyChanged));

    public static void SetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock, string value)
    {
        textBlock.SetValue(FormattedTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static string GetFormattedText(DependencyObject textBlock)
    {
        return (string)textBlock.GetValue(FormattedTextProperty);
    }

    private static void FormattedTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBlock = d as TextBlock;

        if (textBlock == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var formattedText = (string)e.NewValue ?? string.Empty;
        formattedText = string.Format("<Span xml:space=\"preserve\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\">{0}</Span>", formattedText);

        textBlock.Inlines.Clear();
        using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(formattedText)))
        {
            var result = (Span)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**`MainViewModel`**

```
public class MainViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private string _inlineText = "";

    public string InlineText
    {
        get
        {
            return _inlineText;
        }

        set
        {
            _inlineText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("InlineText");
        }
    }
}
```

**`MainWindow.xaml`**

```
<Window x:Class="InlineTextBlockHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:InlineTextBlockHelp.ViewModels"
        xmlns:PropertiesExtension="clr-namespace:InlineTextBlockHelp.PropertiesExtension"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Name="TestText"
                   PropertiesExtension:TextBlockExt.FormattedText="{Binding Path=InlineText, 
                                                                            Mode=TwoWay,
                                                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Width="200"
                   Height="100" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**`Code-behind (just for test)`**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainViewModel mainViewModel = this.DataContext as MainViewModel;

        mainViewModel.InlineText = "<Bold>Once I saw a little bird, go hop, hop, hop.</Bold>";
    }
}
```

> This example is available at this [`link`](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!131&authkey=!AKQ7v2xwk3uavR8&ithint=file%2c.zip).

Comment: I apologize, I was not ignoring you, just got pulled away to put out a fire and just now got back to this.  Thank you that is very helpful in understanding what is going on.  However this requires you to press a button in order to set the text to the new value.  What I really need is to bind the value to a property on my view model, which may change while the interface is open.  I don't see how I can do this... is it possible?  Also I'm upvoting for a very helpful answer but not marking it as answer yet as I'm looking for the binding piece...

Comment: Awesome, marked as answer!  I downloaded your example and the only oddity is that it keeps giving me 'Undefined CLR Namespace' errors for your two custom namespaces.  I have checked them out and they seem to be correct so I'm not sure why.  It builds and functions fine but not sure why the designer show those errors...

Comment: Actually I just modified my project based on what you posted and I don't get the designer errors in my project.  Not sure what the issue is in the sample but doesn't matter.  That is exactly what I needed.  Thank you, wish I could upvote it again!

Comment: This is a great answer and it fixed my problem. Only problem I found is that the `formattedText` in `TextBlockExt.FormattedTextPropertyChanged` should be XML encoded as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/19498780/492 ...but just the plain text in the XML, not the markup.