C# - WPF -TextBlock formatting with binding
This works fine
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Bold>TextBlock</Bold> is designed to be <Italic>lightweight</Italic>,
    and is geared specifically at integrating <Italic>small</Italic> portions
    of flow content into a UI.
</TextBlock>

But I need the inner text to be a data binding to a string
Is this even possible ? I tried different things but I cannot make it work
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FormattedText}" TextWrapping="Wrap">
</TextBlock>

this does not work either
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <Run Text="{Binding FormattedText}"/>
</TextBlock>

the Code behind is this:
public string FormattedText
{
    get { return _formattedText; }
    set
    {
        _formattedText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FormattedText));
    }
}
private string _formattedText;

public MyWpfClass()
{                
   this.InitializeComponent();
   FormattedText = "<Bold>TextBlock</Bold> is designed to be <Italic>lightweight</Italic>, and is geared specifically at integrating<Italic>small</Italic> portions of flow content into a UI.";
}

How can I get formatted text with code behind data binding ?
(The text needs to be a string, not a programmable initialization of a TextBlock)
Thanks for your help
[edit]
I have actually a more complex template
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" Foreground="Black">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Line" Binding="{Binding m_startLine}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start Character" Binding="{Binding m_startCharacter}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Line" Binding="{Binding m_endLine}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End Character" Binding="{Binding m_endCharacter}"/>
        <!-- Modifications -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Modifications">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding m_content}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding .}"/>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>


The usual approach is an attached property that sets the Inlines property: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21894206/1136211

as mentioned, I have complex data, so I cannot do it programmatically, binding must be done on a variable containing an array of strings

The code is too long to paste as an answer, but check out my FormattedTextBlock class which uses tags within the bound Text property (similar to HTML) to control the display layout - details on my blog post http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-formatted-textblock/

I dont see how that post relates to my question, as mentioned I need data binding

The class is designed so you can bind to a single string containing both the text and any required formatting tags. How is that not what you need?

not only TextBlock handles  tag perfectly, once again, mentioned in my question, but, once again, I need data binding, the text and format needs to be in the code behind, not in the template. I dont see anything like that in your post

So you didn't notice how you can set the TextBlock.Text property to something like "Some text with <b>bold</b>, <i>italic</i>, <u>underline</u>, different <fg #FF0000>foreground</fg>, <bg=orange> background </bg>, <fs=32>font size</fs>, <ff=Courier New>font family</ff><lb>line break,<lb>How about some H<sub>2</sub>O or e = mc<sup>2</sup>." either through data binding or direct property access in code behind. The only difference being that the tag items use the standard Html labels  <B> instead of <Bold> etc.

maybe the link you provided is wrong, but there is only templating code and some regex stuff

If you go to the github repository, you can download the entire class, as well as the other libraries and examples from my blog.
https://github.com/Peregrine66/PeregrinesView/blob/master/library/Peregrine.WPF.View/Controls/perFormattedTextBlock.cs

so TextBlock  cannot  handle data binding has is ?
