# Hyperlink keeps failing

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, datagridtemplatecolumn

I am trying to create a hypelink which the user can click and navigate to a website.

The link is working but I am getting this exception which stops the application:
Failed to convert resource into object.

The hyperlink will be a part og a datagrid. Here is what I have:

## XAML:

```
...
<DataTemplate x:Key="hyperlinkTemplate">
    <TextBlock>
        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Link}" RequestNavigate="dataLink_RequestNavigate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskID}"></TextBlock>
        </Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
...

<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name width link" CellTemplate="{StaticResource     hyperlinkTemplate}"></DataGridTemplateColumn>
...
```

==================================================================

## Code behind:

```
...
private void dataLink_RequestNavigate(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Uri.ToString());
    e.Handled = true;
}
...
```

==================================================================

## Class data: Link

```
public string Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set
        {
            link = value;
            Notify("Link");
        }
    }
```

==================================================================

## Task class

```
[Serializable]
public class Task
{
    private XmlNode node;
    private string category = "";
    private int taskID = -1;
    private string taskName = "";
    private string taskResponsible = "";
    private string taskResponsibleDepartment = "";
    private int priority = 5;
    private string status = "Unknown";
    private string predecessorIndices = "None";
    private int indentLevel = 0;
    private int sortOrder = 0;
    private DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
    private TimeSpan estimatedHours = default(TimeSpan);
    private TimeSpan actualHours = default(TimeSpan);
    private DateTime estimatedDeploymentDate = default(DateTime);
    private DateTime desiredImplementationDate = default(DateTime);
    private string estimatedHoursRecovery = "";
    private string actualHoursRecovery = "";
    private string tags = "";
    private TimeSpan totalHoursActual = default(TimeSpan);
    private Department iN = new Department();
    private Department aPP = new Department();
    private Department sIS = new Department();
    private string link = "";
...
```

==================================================================

Do you have any suggestions?

BR

Comment: why do you use both `NavigateUri` property and `RequestNavigate` event ? Shouldn't the former be enough ?

Comment: can you paste the code of the Tasks collection and its type ?

Comment: Why? Is because I have followed the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092890/add-hyperlink-to-textblock-wpf What do you suggest?

Comment: I was only wondering if the NavigateUri itself does not fires the launch of the browser if the hyperlink is using http:// scheme.

Comment: yes... 2 sek. I will just find it

Comment: I cant show you all of it because some parts is confidential :( Sorry

Comment: Yes it does, but it is also NavigateUri that creates the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out myself. I needed to add `e.handled = true;` to the datagrid_RequestNavigate. Just updated the code examples too.

**It is all working now**