# Create textblock with textrun object at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

iam trying to create a TextBlock with runobject at runtime.
i need the textblock to show following text:

Please ***Click Here*** to go to next Page.

Click here should be a "link" like, where the user can click on it and he will move to the next tabitem ..

i have:

```
var tbGoToNextTab = new TextBlock
 {
  Content = "Please Click Here to go to next Page.",
  Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
 };
 
 tbGoToNextTab .Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(tbGoToNextTab_Click);
```

how would i just make the Click Here Clickable, have underline and blue text color and perform an action when clicking on it ?

thanks in advance

## EDIT:

I just want the 2 Words "Click Here" clickable ...the rest should be displayed as normal text..
I think i should be doing this with Inlines.. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (untested)

```
var hyperlink    = new HyperLink(new Run("Click Here"));
hyperlink.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(tbGoToNextTab_Click);

var span = new Span();
span.Inlines.Add(new Run("Please "));
span.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
span.Inlines.Add(new Run(" to go to next Page"));

var tbGoToNextTab = new TextBlock
{
  Content = span,
  Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the Answer ...

As i supposed i had to use the Inline property ..

i found the answer in this post:

[Add hyperlink to textblock wpf From Stanislav Kniazev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2093016/298487)

Thanks all...

Answer (score 0):

Have something like this..
Textblock as content in the button..so that its clickable.

```
        Canvas pnel = new Canvas();
        var btntab = new Button();
        var tbGoToNextTab1 = new TextBlock();
        var tbGoToNextTab2 = new TextBlock();
        var tbGoToNextTab3 = new TextBlock();
        tbGoToNextTab1.Text = "Please ";
        tbGoToNextTab2.Text = "Click Here";
        tbGoToNextTab3.Text = " to go to next Page.";
        tbGoToNextTab1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        btntab.Margin = new Thickness(40, 0, 0, 0);
        tbGoToNextTab3.Margin = new Thickness(95, 0, 0, 0);
        tbGoToNextTab1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tbGoToNextTab2.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        tbGoToNextTab3.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        btntab.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btntab_Click);
        btntab.Content = tbGoToNextTab2;
        pnel.Children.Add(tbGoToNextTab1);
        pnel.Children.Add(btntab);
        pnel.Children.Add(tbGoToNextTab3);
        Text112.Children.Add(pnel);
```

Comment: hi ..this will make the whole text clickable ...i just want the two words "Click Here" to be clickable ...

Comment: Maybe you can have mutiple textblock, making the Click Here inside a button.

Comment: Like this maybe.. but somehow i feel there should be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

To manage a left click action, add a handler on the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`

```
tbGoToNextTab.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OntbGoToNextTabPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;

void OntbGoToNextTabPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // write code here...
    }
```

To manage underline and color change, write a `Style` in xaml, in this Style put a `Trigger` that will change your `TextBlock` on the `IsMouseOver` property change.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="HyperLinkStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="TextDecorations" Value="Underline" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

tbGoToNextTab.Style = FindResource("HyperLinkStyle") as Style;
```

You will have to declare a TextBlock specifically for the clickable text and other TextBlocks for the static text.

Answer (score 0):

If you handle `Click` event for the `TextBlock`, it will process click *anywhere* within the boundary of the control.

If you need only part of the text clickable, you should place a `Hyperlink` within the body of your `TextBlock`. By the way, it has an extra benefit of *highlighting the clickable area* so that your was not confused with the text that says, "Click Here" which is not clickable.

Here's relevant WPF snippet:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run>Please</Run>
    <Hyperlink>
        <Run Text="Click Here"/>
    </Hyperlink>
    <Run>to go to next Page.</Run>
</TextBlock>
```