# How to display links in TextBlock?

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to show a long list of reviews which may contain links. how can I show them so the user can click and open links?

this question has been asked a lot, but I couldn't find a functional answer, this obsolete answer seems isn't working:

```
<TextBlock>
  <Run>let me</Run>
  <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">google</Hyperlink>
  <Run>that for you</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

Also `RichTextBox` doesn't support `Data Binding` does it?

reviews will be shown inside a `LongListSelector` like this:

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Reviews}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Review}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Not working means whats the error?

Comment: @Sajeetharan it doesn't support `Hyperlink` inside it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2093016/352101

Comment: I don't completely get it. Is there a `hyperlink` in your `textblock` but when you click on it, nothing happened ?

Comment: @Hyarantar `TextBlock` doesn't let you insert a `Hyperlink` inside it. my code above will cause an error in VS editor

Comment: Have you tried using NavigateUri ? Bolu linked a post with it.

Comment: @Hyarantar What to do with NavigateUri? my problem is to show clickable text inside a TextBlock. that link is for WPF though

Answer (score 0):

You are missing Text Property,

Here is a complete example of how to add links inside RichTextBox
[Hyperlink inside rich textbox](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-mango-first-look-at-richtextbox-control)

Comment: Will it then support `Data Binding`?!