# Hiding an email address in string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, email, hyperlink

I am building a string in which I have to hide an email address.

```
string StatusText = "Please reach out here for access."
```

Just wanted to know how can we hide an email address in a string. I'd like the "here" to be an email address. I have to bind StatusText to a Textblock such that when user clicks on "here", the outlook mail should open.

Here's the detailed code:

View.xaml

```
<TextBlock   Text="{Binding StatusText}" />
```

ViewModel.cs

```
private string _statusText;
public string StatusText
{
            get { return _statusText; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _statusText, value); }
}


DisplayMessages()
{
  //based on the boolean value, Status Text is set
  //When the case is "NoAccess", I want the "here" of StatusText to be clickable and show the mailaddress as abc@abc.com
  switch(Flag)
   case IsReady:
       StatusText = "Application is Ready";
     break;
   case NoAccess:
     StatusText = "Please reach out here. No access can be provided."
    break;
}
```

Comment: `string contactDetails = "Please reach out to your contact@domain.com for access."` What is your question? Do you mean you want to use a `LinkLabel` control?

Comment: string contactDetails ="mailto:someone@somewhere.com";

Comment: @Saveen What do you think that would achieve?

Comment: OP Could you clarify your question?

Comment: @John I've edited the question for more understanding.

Comment: @john this what he want to achive string myString ="Please reach out to <a href="someone@somewhere.com">here</a>. for access.

Comment: @Saveen Why would that work? OP has said _nowhere_ that they are working with HTML. You understand that, right?

Comment: @john but he added a hyperlink tag in his question

Comment: @Saveen Presumably because that's the closest terminology he knows to describe what he wants to do. From reading his question and seeing that it's tagged wpf, it's clear that he's not talking about HTML.

Comment: I've a Textblock. I am binding and displaying those strings on the Textblock based on condition (switch-case). "Please reach out here for access." is one of the string to be displayed on the Textblock, where I would want the "here" to be clickable. It should open the maild address.

Comment: @john I Agree with you......

Comment: OP does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2092890/add-hyperlink-to-textblock-wpf) answer your question?

Comment: I've provided more details to my question

Comment: @KenY-N Can you please remove the duplicate flag. I don't think it's a duplicate question

Comment: @user42067 They why did not you ask the whole question at once? This is not right way to ask and then gradually edit the question. No one can help your for this kind of approach.

Comment: `StatusText` is not for single purpose. You either can store string or RTF content to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Add the following XAML code inside Window.Resources.

```
<local:DataTemplateSelectorExt x:Key="Selector"></local:DataTemplateSelectorExt>

<DataTemplate x:Key="NoAccess">
        <TextBlock Background="Green">
            <Run Text="Please reach out "/>
            <Hyperlink NavigateUri="abc@gmail.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">here</Hyperlink>
            <Run Text=" for access."/>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
```

**Step 2:**
Replace TextBlock XAML code with the following code snippet.

```
<Label Content="{Binding StatusText}" ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding Source={StaticResource Selector}}" />
```

**Step 3:**
Add the following method inside MainWindow class.

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Popup popup = new Popup { IsOpen = true, Width = 100, Height = 50, Placement = PlacementMode.Mouse };
        popup.Child = new TextBlock { Text = (sender as Hyperlink).NavigateUri.ToString(), Background = Brushes.Green };
        popup.IsOpen = true;            
    }
```

**Step 4:**
Finally add the below class in your project.

```
public class DataTemplateSelectorExt : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item == null) return (DataTemplate)null;

        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (item.Equals("Please reach out here. No access can be provided."))
            return Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("NoAccess") as DataTemplate;

            return null;
    }
}
```

Hope, this will meet your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much. That's exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would you to take advantage of `XAML`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Please reach out "/>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="YOUR_URL_FOR_OUTLOOK" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">here</Hyperlink>
    <Run Text=" for access."/>
</TextBlock>
```

In code behind

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The main benefit of using this approach is that you can use `Binding` to bind your emailId to `Hyperlink`.

Your output will look like this in Viewer
[image]

Comment: I've added more details to my question