# regexp parsing error in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have html which contains such text

```
.......
<a class="product_name" href="index.php?productID=29785">Funny</a>
........
<a class="product_name" href="index.php?productID=29787">Very Funny</a>
......
```

I'd like to *href* attribute value and text into link so I'd like to get

```
"index.php?productID=29785", "Funny"
"index.php?productID=29787", "Very Funny"
```

And I use

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(pageData, 
   "<a class=\"product_name\" href=\"(.+)\">(.+)</a>");
```

For this. But when I debug code I saw that mc.Count = 0

I think I didn't escaped quotes properly, but I don't know.

Comment: Parsing html with regex is infamously not a good idea

Comment: I get count=2 here, btw, with capture-groups that work as expected. The regex shown works for the html shown. If it isn't working, then either a: you aren't presenting the scenario identically, or b: the html is more complicated, making it insanely hard for all the many reasons that you shouldn't parse html with regex

Comment: Agreed. It works here as well (http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with regex. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for a compelling reason why.

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) instead.

Comment: Regex is not good for parsing html, but I wouldn't include a new dependency to my project for such a simple task.

Comment: @L.B - What would you suggest then? Writing your own parser/tokenizer?

Comment: @L.B - You seem to be contradicting yourself. _"Regex is not good for parsing html"_ ... _"I would use Regex"_.

Answer (score -1):

Review the following threads to find possible solution(s):

http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

[Regex to Parse Hyperlinks and Descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323/regex-to-parse-hyperlinks-and-descriptions)

[Parse HTML links using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122856/parse-html-links-using-c-sharp)

Comment: -1 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454