# Regular Expression to find all links in webpage

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am trying to find all of the links in source code on a website, could anyone tell me the expression i would need to put in my Regex to find these?

---

Duplicate of (among others): [Regular expression for parsing links from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173/regular-expression-for-parsing-links-from-a-webpage)

Google finds more: [html links regex site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+links+regex+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score -3):

I'm not certain how these would translate to C# (I haven't done any development in C# myself yet), but here's how I might do it in JavaScript or ColdFusion. It might give you an idea about how you want to do it in C#.

In JavaScript I *think* this would work:

```
rex = /.*href="([^"]+)"/; 
a = source.replace(rex,'\n$1').split('\n');
```

after which a would be an array containing the links... though I'm not certain if that will work exactly the way I think it will. The idea here is that the replace creates a line-break-delimited list (because you can't have a line-break in a URL) and then you can break apart the list with split() to get your array.

By comparison in ColdFusion you would have to do something slightly different:

```
a = REMatch('href="[^"]+"',source); 
for (i = 1; i < ArrayLen(a); i++) {
  a[i] = mid(a[i],6,len(a[i])-1); 
}
```

Again, I haven't tested it, but rematch returns an array of instances of the expression and then the for-next loop removes the href="" around the actual URL.

Comment: The question is tagged with C#.