# Regular expression for remove html links

Tags: html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for parsing links from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173/regular-expression-for-parsing-links-from-a-webpage)
>   [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

i need a regular expression to strip html `<a>` tags , here is sample:

```
<a href="xxxx" class="yyy" title="zzz" ...> link </a>
```

should be converted to

```
 link
```

Comment: Do you 'need' a regular expression?

Comment: @josh3736 I will feast on your Unicorn's blood.

Comment: In what language?  HTML doesn't have regular expressions.

Answer (score 13):

I think you're looking for: `</?a(|\s+[^>]+)>`

Comment: When have you ever seen just an <a> tag?

Comment: I edited it to account for strange cases like that anyway.

Comment: Doesn't match `< a>` or `< /a>`.

Answer (score 3):

Answers given above would match valid html tags such as `<abbr>` or `<address>` or `<applet>` and strip them out erroneously. A better regex to match only anchor tags would be

```
</?a(?:(?= )[^>]*)?>
```

Comment: I've used this one with the free edition of sublime text 3. Worked best in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to use this hackish solution iteratively, and it won't probably even work perfectly for complicated HTML:

```
<a(\s[^>]*)?>.*?(</a>)?
```

Alternatively, you can try one of the **existing HTML sanitizers/parsers** out there.

---

HTML is not a regular language; **any** regex we give you will *not* be 'correct'. **It's impossible.** Even Jon Skeet and Chuck Norris can't do it. Before I lapse into a fit of rage, like [@bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) [in]famously once did, I'll just say this:

### Use a HTML Parser.

***(Whatever they're called.)***

---

#### EDIT:

If you want to 'incorrectly' strip out `</a>`s that don't have any `<a>`s as well, do this:

```
</?[a\s]*[^>]*>
```

Comment: Your regex: `<a(\s[^>]*)?>(</a>)?` does not match `</a>` closing tags (except for the case where the A element is empty).

Comment: @ridgerunner Since regexes don't have memory, putting a `.*?` in between the two is the best I can do. It'll break down for more complicated HTML.

Comment: Just curious: Why are you worried about the tag's text at all?

Comment: @BillCriswell Oh, damn, I just realized the OP probably doesn't need a 'regex' which will  *not* strip out unmatched `</a>`s. (That would be incorrect, but I don't think the OP would care. :))

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I would use:

`</?a\b[^>]*>`

Answer (score 1):

`</?a.*?>` would work. Replace it with `''`

Comment: i just make a little change that works for me. thanks for help.     /<a.*?>/ , edit your answer.

Comment: Yes of course, I merely gave the RE. You would have to append the `/` prefix/suffix if you were using javascript for instance. You would not have to add anything if you were using the C# regex library.

Comment: but there is a little problem. the &lt;/a> not striped .

Comment: are you using POSIX or PCRE? i.e `ereg_replace` or `preg_replace`

Comment: You're stripping away the whole of `<a><img></img>blahblah</a>`. (JavaScript regexes are greedy, right?)

Comment: @muntoo- no it will not. It will find a match in `<a>` and stop. and then find another match at `</a>`. The `.*?` makes the search for `.*` non-greedy.

Comment: FYI: This also matches elements like <abbr>, <acronym>, <address>, <applet> and <area>.

Comment: @muntoo - Yes, Javascript regex quantifiers are greedy by default, but can be made non-greedy (or _lazy_) by appending a `?` after the quantifier. i.e. `.*` is greedy but `.*?` is lazy.

Comment: @Bill Criswell - Agreed, your solution would be better.