# c# url extraction by regular expression

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for parsing links from a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6173/regular-expression-for-parsing-links-from-a-webpage)

How can I find all urls from HTML using regular expression. I need only url for pages so I want to add exclusion of urls which end with ".css" or ".jpg" or ".js" etc.

Example of HTML:

```
<a href=index.php?option=content&amp;task=view&amp;id=2&amp;Itemid=25 class="menu_selected" id="">Home</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://data.stackexchange.com">data</a> |
                <a href="http://shop.stackexchange.com/">shop</a> |
                <a href="http://stackexchange.com/legal">legal</a> |
```

Thanks

Comment: string strRef = @"(href|HREF)[ ]*=[ ]*[""'][^""'#>]+[""']";
                   
     MatchCollection matches = new Regex(strRef).Matches(strResponse);

Answer (score 2):

If you can, avoid using Regular Expressions, but instead use a proper HTML parser. For example, reference the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), and use the following:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(yourHtmlInput);
foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
                              ?? Enumerable.Empty<HtmlNode>())
{
    string href = link.Attributes["href"].Value;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(href))
    {
        // Act on the link here, including ignoring it if it's a .jpg etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think, regular expression will be faster than HTML Agility Pack; please correct if I am wrong

Comment: It will probably be faster; HTML Agility Pack is likely to be more robust. I really only posted this because I had the code to hand from a project I did recently :)

Comment: RegEx won't work at all: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html . Simple rule of thumb: use Regular Expressions to parse "Regular Languages" - HTML is not a "Regular Language" (refer to the Chomsky Hierarchy for more information).

Comment: Regex might be faster but parsing HTML with regex is problematic.  How many do you need to parse?

Comment: I need to parse so many pages(upto 5000). The application is multithreaded so I want each thread to finish work soon

Comment: 5 thosand is not so many.  Maybe give HTML Agility Pack a try.

Comment: @Blam At least it's not over 9000.